# if column A text "customer account" and column M <=0 delete all rows between

Tags: excel, vba

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBsTj.png)[image]

Trying to delete complete rows if criteria met. If column A has text "customer account" and column M <=0 then delete all rows between. 
It doesn't give any error but does not delete the rows

```
Dim sh As Worksheet

Set sh = Sheets("RAW DATA FILE")

Dim x As Long, lastrow As Long
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For x = lastrow To 1 Step -1
    If Cells(x, 2).Value = "customer account" And Cells(x, 13) <= 0 Then
        Rows(x).Delete
    End If
Next x
```

Comment: For the rows between text "customer account" on column A and if negative value on cell column M want to delete all rows.

Comment: `Cells(x, 2)` is checking B not A.

Comment: no, need to delete rows please

Comment: sorry, column B - have column A hiding

Comment: Lastrow will give you the last row of the currently active sheet, not `sh`. Furthermore, you also don't use your parent sheet when you reference other cells in column a or m

Comment: In fact, there is no reference to `sh` at all. All your `Cells` calls have an implicit `ActiveSheet` (and the `Rows` too).

Comment: A filter here would be *much* more efficient than looping through rows.

Comment: Column 2 (B) has different text, not just "customer account" - cannot filter since there might be other negative values

Comment: Wish i could post a picture of the file for you guys better understand

Comment: @BrunoFerreira you can. Add a link and someone can edit it into your question.

Comment: ALREADY DID, THANK YOU SO MUCH

Comment: in the example image i uploaded, what i need to do is delete from B2 to M6 if value on M6 <=0. And need to loop to go through the file

Comment: You are creating more confusion through your last comment. At least with me. What do you mean by looping through the file. Do you mean all worksheets? I now see that your intention is to delete a whole range of rows. And not line by line.

Comment: @JvdV sadly that missing detail (hence my original question about the meaning of "between") means we have to throw the filter or loop approach out completely, sorry for you to do all that work.

Comment: @BigBen, its fine. The loop still works. We just need to check the `Offset`. Will post an update.

Comment: As long as the structure of each set of rows is the same, yes. But... this kind of feels like a bait-and-switch on OP's part.

Comment: Yes, sorry for confusion. Waht need to do is delete a range of rows between text "customer account" and "currency" if in the row for "currency" cell on column M is <=0

Comment: The structure of each set of rows is the same = Column A from text "customer account" to "currency"

Comment: have uploaded a new image of file - offset needs to be to each range or rows? How to count them for each range of rows?

Comment: @BigBen, you were completely right about the bait =). So much for [ask] a question with a [mcve].....

Comment: i am sorry for the time wasting to all, will improve how to make qustions and mark them as answered. Thank you so much all for your help & availability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your current problem could be that you are using a reference to the currently active sheet. You came as far as declaring a parent sheet (`sh`) but never used it as such. You can overcome that with a simple `With`:

```
Dim sh As Worksheet: Set sh = Sheets("RAW DATA FILE")
Dim x As Long, lastrow As Long

With sh
    lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For x = lastrow To 1 Step -1
        If .Cells(x, 2).Value = "customer account" And .Cells(x, 13) <= 0 Then
            .Rows(x).Delete
        End If
    Next x
End with
```

---

That leaves the question wheather or not there are better, faster ways in getting your result. As per @BigBen, you should look into using a filter instead. You could try:

```
Dim sh As Worksheet: Set sh = Sheets("RAW DATA FILE")
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim rng As Range

With sh
    lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = .Range("A1:M" & lastrow)
    rng.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="customer account"
    rng.AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:="<=0"
    rng.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    rng.AutoFilter
End With
```

This is assuming you are using a header row.

---

**EDIT:**

If your intention is to delete a whole range of rows, `AutoFilter` is not an option nomore. In that case a loop did the trick, but you'll need some `Offset` to check for your column `M` value:

```
Dim sh As Worksheet: Set sh = Sheets("Blad1")
Dim x As Long, lastrow As Long

With sh
    lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For x = lastrow To 1 Step -1
        If .Cells(x, 2).Value = "customer account" And .Cells(x, 13).Offset(4, 0) <= 0 Then
            .Range(x & ":" & x + 4).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next x
End With
```

This will delete the rows between AND the rows that are checked. If this is not what you want then you should use: `.Range(x+1 & ":" & x + 3).EntireRow.Delete`

Comment: I have tried this code and got no errors but still not deleting the range of rows

Comment: Have not much experience with filter but how can i do with 2 criteria please?

Comment: @BrunoFerreira, I've updated. See if that worked. If not, then at least there should be enough clues in there for you to pick onto and work with yourself. Good luck =)

Comment: @BrunoFerreira, that's a shame. As this worked perfectly on my end, I cannot assist you any further due to lack of clarity from your end.

Comment: i have uploaded a new image from sheet, can you please check? Thank you so much

Comment: @BrunoFerreira, your lack of information made for multiple people trying to help you spending time on your case. If you can't produce a clear question, then you get answers that won't fit your case. See [ask] a question with a [mcve]. Try to understand what is going wrong here (your offset differs). Study the code and return when you can reproduce what is asked in the links I just shared with you. Right now, I feel like we going back and forth.

Comment: Understand, thank you so much for your availability. will check and open new question to clarify

Comment: @BrunoFerreira, one more thing for you to address. You have a ton of open question which non of them have an accepted answer. Going through them, multiple of them can be closed. Read the rules of this website, take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and upvote/accept answers before opening more questions.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below

```
Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = Sheets("RAW DATA FILE")
Dim x As Long, lastrow As Long
lastrow = sh.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For x = lastrow To 1 Step -1
    If sh.Cells(x, 1).Value = "customer account" And sh.Cells(x, 13) <= 0 Then
        sh.Rows(x).Delete
    End If
Next x
```