# Find and delete row with multiple criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of student records listed with surname in column B and first name in column C. On the user form is a search function which fills in the student name into the value surname.value and firstname.value, i then want a command button to find that person on the record list and delete the entire row. I had this coding working with message boxes, i then changed the message box to delete row and now it does not work.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("-student records no CVI")


     Dim rngFound As Range
    Dim strFirst As String
    Dim strID As String
    Dim strDay As String

    strID = Surname.Value
    strDay = Firstname.Value

    Set rngFound = Columns("B").Find(strID, Cells(Rows.Count, "B"), xlValues, xlWhole)
    If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then
        strFirst = rngFound.Address
        Do
            If LCase(Cells(rngFound.row, "C").Text) = LCase(strDay) Then
                'Found a match
                ws.Rows(rngFound.row).EntireRow.Delete

            End If
            Set rngFound = Columns("B").Find(strID, rngFound, xlValues, xlWhole)
        Loop While rngFound.Address <> strFirst
    End If

    Set rngFound = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: When deleting rows, you have to step backwards, starting at the last row, or you end up with all kinds of problems like this. There are plenty of posts here about deleting rows in Excel for you to review.

Comment: Use `AutoFilter`.=). No loop needed.

Comment: @JvdV I had a feeling there was a better way :) please post an answer of you want

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58607473/9758194) is a link to a recent answer I gave with a certain part that describes how to use `AutoFilter`. Feel free to implement it in your answer to complement it if you want.

Comment: Both answers are good, but they will run into a problem when there are students with the same name, both answers will delete all the names that match. I would suggest that you assign a student ID# and use it to find and delete a specific student.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am by no means a professional just FYI, I'm not sure if this is the best way to do this, but it's how I'd do it.

**Update (I did say I wasn't a professional!):**

The second answer code will first search for Surname, then check Given Name, but it would match "John Smith" to "John Smithfalls" as it doesn't do "exact string", just needs the string to be present. It is also less efficient then using ["AutoFilter".](https://trumpexcel.com/vba-autofilter/) Based on the other answer and comments I made another answer as well to update this. (Accepted answers always show on top of page regardless of votes).

**Using `AutoFilter`:**

```
Sub Remove_Student()

Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")

Dim SurnameStr As String, GivenNameStr As String
SurnameStr = "Smith"
GivenNameStr = "Joe"

With ws
 .AutoFilterMode = False
 With .Range("A1")
  .AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:=SurnameStr
  .AutoFilter field:=3, Criteria1:=GivenNameStr
 End With
 .AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
 .AutoFilterMode = False
End With
End Sub
```

**Using `InStr`:**

```
Sub Remove_Student()

Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")

Dim SurnameStr As String, GivenNameStr As String
SurnameStr = "Smith"
GivenNameStr = "Joe"

Dim lRow
lRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

Dim rcell As Range, rng As Range
Set rng = ws.Range("B1:B" & lRow)

For Each rcell In rng.Cells
 If InStr(1, Range(rcell.Address), SurnameStr, vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then
 'MsgBox SurnameStr & " Found in Row " & rcell.Row
  If InStr(1, Range(rcell.Offset(0, 1).Address), GivenNameStr, vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then
   'rcell.EntireRow.Delete
   MsgBox SurnameStr & " , " & GivenNameStr & " Found in Row " & rcell.Row
  End If
 End If
Next rcell

End Sub
```

Comment: You should match the entire content of the cell.  Searching for `John Stock`  will delete `John Stock` and `John Stockman`.

Comment: @TinMan I did know that but should have included that.

Comment: But would Autofilter catch 'Mr John Stock' ?

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers, It would definately if your `Criteria` includes a wildcard, e.g.: `"* John Stock"`

Comment: You are talking apples and oranges; the OP specifically identified columns B and C as containing student Last and First names. It would be more efficient to use a filter when using a form to find a students' name on a worksheet.

Answer (score 3):

Simple way of deleting rerords using `Autofilter`:

```
Sub Remove_Student()
Dim Ws As Worksheet
Dim strID As String
Dim strDay As String

Set Ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
strID = Surname.Value
strDay = Firstname.Value

Ws.AutoFilterMode = False
Ws.Range("A1").AutoFilter 2, strID
Ws.Range("A1").AutoFilter 3, strDay
Ws.AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
Ws.AutoFilterMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: You should handle the error throm by `SpecialCells` when no match is found.

Comment: @TinMan, no handler needed, no errors will be thrown :)

Comment: Yes. No error will be thrown as header row is always there.

Comment: I would use `With ws`

Comment: Did you try this? Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but I'm getting `Method of Range Class Failed`

Comment: I didn't have anything in Row 1 A1, as @TinMan mentioned, fixed now :)